# Dropping frames of sections and subsections titles for knitr beamer slides

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, beamer

When making beamer slides with `knitr` using the Frankfurt theme the PDF output includes slides with the section and subsection names.

````
---
title: Movies
author: Chewy
output:
  beamer_presentation:
  slide_level: 3
theme: "Frankfurt"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

#Introduction

##Background

###History

A long time ago ...

###History

... in a galaxy far far away

#The End

##This the end

### My only friend, the end
````

Giving this output...

**Slides 1-4:**

[image]

**Slides 5-8:**

[image]

How do I get rid of the slides (2,3,6 and 7) with the section and subsection titles whilst maintaining the document structure displayed at the top of the slides?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those frames are produced by the commands `\AtBeginSubsection{}` and `\AtBeginSection{}`, which you can redefine in your YAML front matter to do nothing instead:

```
---
header-includes: 
- \AtBeginSubsection{}
- \AtBeginSection{}
---
```

Comment: Thanks @soca. In my non-simplified application I also have a `beamer_presentation:   includes:   in_header: header.txt` for my Beamer preamble. Your answer seems to make this call to `header.txt` no longer function. Any ideas how I can include both?

Comment: you could just add those two lines, without the leading `-`, in your header.txt

Comment: Awesome. Worked a treat!